# Thrift Concurrency: Unresolved externals

Tags: c++, thrift

I'm attemtping to upgrade our thrift simple server to a nonblocking server.  In order to do so, I had to link the thriftnb lib.  Linking the nb lib fixed unresolved external errors related to the nonblocking server; however, I am still getting unresolved externals for the thread factories... eg... posix or boost thread factory.  I would assume thrift concurrency also lives in the nb lib (or the general thrift lib).  As far as I can tell, there are only two thrift libs, so what am I missing?

Thanks!

thrift 0.11
C++ 11

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/26233563

Comment: This is not a general question about unresolved externals.  It is a specific question about thrift libs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why the boost and posix thread factories are missing, but the StdThreadFactory is working.  For anyone that is interested, this is my config:

```
std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolFactory());
        std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TProcessor> processor(new cimnetservicerefactor::CIMNetServiceRefactorProcessor(stdHandler));
        std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::TProcessorFactory> processorFactory(new apache::thrift::TSingletonProcessorFactory(processor));
        std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TNonblockingServerTransport> serverTransport(new LocalhostOnlyServerSocket(port, machineName, localConnectionsOnly));
        shared_ptr<apache::thrift::concurrency::StdThreadFactory> threadFactory = shared_ptr<apache::thrift::concurrency::StdThreadFactory>(new apache::thrift::concurrency::StdThreadFactory());
        threadManager->threadFactory(threadFactory);
        threadManager->start();
        apache::thrift::server::TNonblockingServer server(processorFactory, protocolFactory, serverTransport, threadManager);
```